# how to reload the pop up window on clicking close button in pop up window?

Tags: jquery

i am displaying videos in my popup window on selection of the video link.  The video is playing well. But after closing the popup and when i try to play another video, it tends to play the previous video in the top and below the newly clicked video link is being played.

is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you show your code on fiddle ?

Comment: post some code samples.

Comment: function popup() {
    debugger;
   
    $('#display_videos').css("display", "block");
    $('#display_videos').dialog({
        buttons: [{
            text: 'Close',
            handler: function() {
                $('#display_videos').dialog('close');
            }
}]


        });
    }

Comment: ('#display_videos') thats the div where i play the videos on selection of the link.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if and only if you are populating the video in the div dynamically.

```
function popup() { 
$('#display_videos').css("display", "block"); 
$('#display_videos').dialog({ 
buttons: [{ text: 'Close', handler: function() {       
$('#display_videos').html('')  ;
$('#display_videos').dialog('close');
} 
}] 
});
 }
```

Comment: i am playing my videos dynamically only. but that part of code is not working.

Comment: Then I need some more code sample to resolve this issue.

Comment: function ShowVideo(Id) {
    var ViedoId = Id;
    GetVideo(ViedoId);
      popup();
}    on clicking of link this particular function gets executed,

Answer (score 0):

```
 function GetVideo(VideoId) {
        var id = VideoId;
// videoid is the id of the video selected by clicking on the link.
        $.ajax
    ({
         type: "POST",
         url: "KtVideosDocs.aspx/Play_Videos_Kt",
         data: "{'VideoId': '" + VideoId + "'}",
         contentType: "application/json",
         dataType: "json",
         success: function(xyz) {
             var tabledata = [];
             var data = jQuery.parseJSON(xyz.d);
            var FileName = data[0].FileName;
```

$('#tblplayvideos tbody>tr:last').after('');
            },
             error: function(x, e) {
                 alert(x.responseText);
             }

```
     });
    }
this function takes the video selected and plays it
```